# navigateUp() and navigate(action_id) not working as expected

Tags: android, navigation

Using the Navigation framework, I navigate from a `Homefragment` to a `WhsSearchWebDB` and back to the  `Homefragment`.

When coming back via `navController.navigate(R.id.action_whsSearchWebDB_to_nav_home)` or `navController.navigateUp()`, the screen is completely white and the `toolbar` is only partially updated: the name of the fragment is correctly set, but the navigation button shows a back arrow instead of the three-bar-home icon.

When coming back via the back button (`navController.navigate(R.id.action_whsSearchWebDB_to_nav_home)` and `navController.navigateUp()` commented, of course), everything works fine.

I need to come back programmatically, not through a user click on the back button. What must I change?

mobile_navigation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
app:startDestination="@id/nav_home">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:name="be.ema.golfclubdataconversion.ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_whsSearchWebDB"
        app:destination="@id/whsSearchWebDB" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
    android:name="be.ema.golfclubdataconversion.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
    android:name="be.ema.golfclubdataconversion.ui.slideshow.SlideshowFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_slideshow"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_slideshow" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/whsSearchWebDB"
    android:name="be.ema.golfclubdataconversion.ui.WhsSearchWebDB"
    android:label="WhsSearchWebDB"
    tools:layout="@layout/search_web_db">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_whsSearchWebDB_to_nav_home"
        app:destination="@id/nav_home" />
</fragment>
```

home_fragment code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
public static View root = null;
private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View root, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onViewCreated(root, savedInstanceState);

//        homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

    Button openUrlBtn = root.findViewById(R.id.openUrlBtn);
    openUrlBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment);
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_whsSearchWebDB);
        }
    });
}
}
```

WhsSearchWebDB code :

```
public class WhsSearchWebDB extends Fragment {
public static Activity activity;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_web_db, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View root, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(root, savedInstanceState);
    activity = getActivity();

    String urlToBeOpened = "http://ncrdb.usga.org";

    WebView webView = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            /* This call inject JavaScript into the page which just finished loading. */
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(urlToBeOpened);
}

public static class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processHTML(String html) {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

//            navController.navigate(R.id.action_whsSearchWebDB_to_nav_home);
//            if (!navController.navigateUp()) {
//                System.out.println("nooooooo !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
//            }
    }
}
}
```

**** EDIT ****
This is the expected screen (picture taken before going to the `WhsSearchWebDB` fragment:
[image]

And this is the incorrect result after trying to come back:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered that the `processHTML` method executes on a background thread, hence not allowed to manipulate UI widgets. I had preferred a crash/error instead of the unexpected behavior I have reported in my question.

I have fixed the issue by implementing a `ViewModel`, *selecting* the result in the `processHTML` method and *observing* it on the UI thread as follows:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View root, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(root, savedInstanceState);
    activity = getActivity();

    String urlToBeOpened = "http://ncrdb.usga.org";

    WebView webView = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            /* This call inject JavaScript into the page which just finished loading. */
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(urlToBeOpened);

    TeeboxViewModel teeboxViewModel = new ViewModelProvider((ViewModelStoreOwner) activity).get(TeeboxViewModel.class);
    teeboxViewModel.getSelected().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), item -> {
        ...
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_whsSearchWebDB_to_nav_newResult);
    });
}

public static class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    public static Map<String, String> coursesList = new HashMap<>();
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processHTML(String html) {
            ...
            TeeboxViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider((ViewModelStoreOwner) activity).get(TeeboxViewModel.class);
            model.select(teeboxesList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Navigation Action in the whsSearchWebDB Fragment is creating a new fragment not popping back to the original fragment.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/whsSearchWebDB"
    android:name="be.ema.golfclubdataconversion.ui.WhsSearchWebDB"
    android:label="WhsSearchWebDB"
    tools:layout="@layout/search_web_db">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_whsSearchWebDB_to_nav_home"
        // Change this
        app:destination="@id/nav_home"
        // To this to pop back
        app:popUpTo="@id/nav_home" />
```

I didn't include popUpToInclusive.
PopUPToInclusive needs to be set to true, the popUpTo attribute will remove all destinations up to and including the given destination from the back stack.

1. Open the navigation graph
2. Select the action, you want
3. In the attributes pane, set popUptToInclusive the homeFragment, Select the popUpToInclusive check box to true.

For more details please check out the Navigation code lab.
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation#6

Comment: no change, neither with `navigateUp()`, nor with `navigate(R.id.action_whsSearchWebDB_to_nav_home)`. The back-arrow still works fine

Comment: @ema3272 I've updated my answer, that should help.